# jQuery keypress is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to add a textarea after a button is clicked. However, although the button click works, the textarea does not register any keypress events.

NOTE: There is a list of different files which why I attach a unique id to its id.

```
$(".add").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#" + id).after("<textarea placeholder = 'Add a description for this piece of work. Press enter to save it.' class = 'edit-work' id = 'edit-work" + id + "'></textarea>");
    $("textarea").not("#edit-work"+id).remove();                     
});

$(".edit-work").on('keypress', function(e) {
    alert('foo');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you bind the `keypress` listener to the textarea, the textarea doesn't exist. You need to bind the keypress to the document (or an existing parent)

```
$(document).on('keypress', ".edit-work", function(e){
    alert('foo');
});
```

More info on event delegation [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. I don't quite understand why my original code didn't work though.

Comment: Because when you used `$(".edit-work").on('keypress'` .edit-work doesn't exist. If you bind it after appending that will work, or use event delegation as my example :)

Answer (score 0):

`$(".edit-work").on('keypress', ...)` will only register the handler on currently existing `.edit-work` elements. If you add a new one, it will not have a handler attached. It's like telling all your employees not to produce any paper documentation, then hiring someone new without telling him anything, then wondering why he's doing the traditional office stuff with paper.

You want the live handler: `$(editWorkAncestor).on('keypress', '.edit-work', ...)`, with `editWorkAncestor` being a `document`, or any node under which your `.edit-work` will appear (or a selector for one such). This will attach the handler to the ancestor, which will check each time if the event target matches the provided live selector.